# Digital clocking systems/software? (employee clocking)

Tags: system, clock, time-and-attendance

How does a digital clocking system deal with user error such as someone forgetting to clock out or someone erroneously entering their code causing them to clock someone else in/out (who might not even be on the schedule that day). Its obvious there could be issues of dishonesty, but what about human error?

Comment: Schweet...thanks for the down vote that's really necessary and helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better T&A (time & attendance) programs actually let this be configured in any of a number of ways. (Btw, typically the clocking software itself just marks down a "transaction" - this employee at that time did this thing - with no further processing, leaving that to the T&A system.)

- Have a "hard" clock out time - e.g. even if you forgot to clock out when you leave at 5, you're automatically clocked out at 6.
- Rollover - leave the employee clocked in, even till tomorrow, and then just have extra clockin in the morning.
- Mark the workday as "incomplete", and expect the employee to submit their actual times manually.
- Cancel the entire workday
- Dont clock the employee out automatically, but transfer him after a certain time to another, default charge code (where this is relevant).
- Run some other custom scripted action...

It's important to note, that all of these results are "legitimate", depending on the organization, contracts, etc.

Now, wrt to entering the wrong employee code - most often it's based on an employee card (or even some form of biometric scanner), but when the employee is expected to manually type in their code, the console should display the employee's name, for verification, and then a second "approve" button.
Also, to some extent this can be discovered automatically and flagged for manual followup, for instance in the case where night-shift employees are shown as clocking in the morning, or HQ personnel clocking at a remote branch office.

Answer (score 0):

so if it is to prevent human error, a password which is actually a "verification code" can be used.  So if Joe is 0123 and Mary is 0124, Joe's entering 0123 needs to be matched with his entering verification code of 8888 so that the system knows it is really Joe, not Mary entering 0123 by accident.

Comment: Thats what I don't get all the systems ive seen don't have a verification code.

Comment: Why is that, Haven't those developers figured it out?

Comment: hm... in my past experience, sometimes the person who wrote the requirement or the spec, or the programmer didn't think too much about it. Sometimes they just write the program and it works, and they don't care about the case where what if someone makes a mistake or something like that. some people also would rather go socialize with the manager or the boss instead of writing a better program.

Comment: That makes sense unfortunately.

Comment: No, its actually a usability requirement - a second verification code makes it more complicated, and in truth would not add much, especially since there's a non-negligible chance that Mary's code will also be 8888.

Answer (score 0):

The system must allow to print a preview of the final time sheet. Employees then get a copy, can verify it and return fixes (signed by their boss). These get merged with the data that already exists.

Unless you hijack your employees, force a RFID into their spine and make them crawl through a scanner tube four times a way, that's the most simple, secure and reality-prone solution.

Comment: That wouldn't be secure.  It would be fairly simple for a third party to read and duplicate the RFID tag.